# How to have two forms docked on same side (Weifenluo)

Tags: vb.net, docking, dockpanel-suite

I've been searching quite a lot and studying the Docksuite sample but haven't been successful in getting a simple screen working. I would like to have a form on top and two forms opened on the left.

What I have done so far:

1. Created a FormMainDock that holds a DockPanel; isMDIContainer = True
2. Created three Forms that inherit from DockContent
3. In the FormMainDock have the following code:

...

```
Private Sub FormMainDock_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Me.DockPanel1.Theme = New VS2015DarkTheme
  Dim fTop As New FormTop
  fTop.Show(DockPanel1, DockState.DockTop)
  fTop.DockPanel.DockTopPortion = 120

  Dim fLeft1 As New FormLeft1
  fLeft1.Show(DockPanel1, DockState.DockLeft)

  Dim fLeft2 As New FormLeft2
  fLeft2.Show(DockPanel1, DockState.DockLeft)
  fLeft2.DockPanel.DockLeftPortion = 400

End Sub
```

...

and that shows me

[image: Example 1]

Now what I would like to have is this

[image: Example 2]

I have no idea how to get the two forms opened on startup.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Insert 2 forms into TableLayoutPanel and then dock it or anchor to 4 sides.

Comment: https://ibb.co/WkbxKdv

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out but I really want the functionality of the dockingpanel suite. Like moving forms, closing and or re-open them, docking in any direction at any location. I know you can get very far by using Split-containers and the TableLayoutPanel, but using the Dockingpanel is what it\this is meant for.

Comment: https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues/267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I already looked at the demo source, I looked again, knowing that this code worked and the tip from Lex Li to look at it again I forced myself to dive a bit deeper, and with the help of some C# translators I figured it out. Of course in the end it is quite simple. So for anyone else to solve it quicker here is all you have to do:

First, create a MainForm that holds a DockPanel and set isMDIContainer = True.
Create three Forms that inherit from DockContent (don't forget to Import the WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking). Then when you want to get the sample that is in the picture use this:

```
Private Sub FormMainDock_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Me.DockPanel1.Theme = New VS2015DarkTheme 'This line isn't necessary

  Dim fTop As New FormTop
  fTop.Show(DockPanel1, DockState.DockTop)

  Dim fLeft1 As New FormLeft1
  fLeft1.Show(DockPanel1, DockState.DockLeft)

  Dim fLeft2 As New FormLeft2
  fLeft2.Show(fLeft1.Pane, DockAlignment.Bottom, 0.5)
End Sub
```

That's all. Have fun with it.